# Is there some way in scala that I can return a type?

Tags: scala, reflection, types, pattern-matching, scala-reflect

I have a lot of classes such as `DataFrameFlow`, `TextFlow`, `RDDFlow`. They all derive from base class `Flow`.

Now I want to write a function `judgeFlow` which can read from a `path: String` and return something representing exact `Flow` type from which I can create corresponding instance. The whole code seems like the following

```
def judgeFlow(path:String) = /*1*/ {
  Flow.getStoreType(path) match {
    case StoreType.tdw =>
      DataFrameFlow
    case StoreType.hdfs =>
      TextFlow
  }
}

def createFlow(typeInfo:/*2*/) = /*3*/{
  new typeInfo()
}
```

However, I don't know how to write in place 1, 2 and 3.

EDIT

Knowing how to construct them is not enough here, because I also want the following:

1. pattern matching through `typeInfo`
2. some ways to do `asInstanceOf`

EDIT 2

Definition of `Flow`

```
abstract class Flow(var outputName: String) extends Serializable{
  def this() = this("")
...
}
```

Definition of `DataFrameFlow`

```
class DataFrameFlow(d: DataFrame, path: String) extends Flow {
  var data: DataFrame = d

  def this(data: DataFrame) = this(data, "")
  def this(path: String) = this(null, path)
  def this() = this(null, "")
...
}
```

Comment: If all you plan to do with the thing is construct it, you may consider returning a 0-ary function which does the construction.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Doing construction is not enough, I need something for asInstanceOf as well

Comment: Your example is not representative, how your classes are(`Flow`,`DataFrameFlow`, etc )? For example `case class Flow(id: Int, ....)` and it would be fine some data examples too.

Comment: @Chema Their definition is too big and I think they do not matter. `Flow` is a abstract class and `DataFrameFlow` inherits it. I am trying to provide more detailed code, but it will take some time

Comment: Hi @calvin, If they were case classes you could do pattern matching to build your objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pattern matching can't return different types from different cases. The type returned by pattern matching is the least upper bound of types returned in cases.

When someone wants to return different types, most probably he/she wants a type class.

```
sealed abstract class Flow
class DataFrameFlow extends Flow
class TextFlow extends Flow
class RDDFlow extends Flow

trait JudgeFlow[In] {
  type Out <: Flow
  def judgeFlow(in: In): Out
}
object JudgeFlow {
  implicit val `case1`: JudgeFlow[???] { type Out = DataFrameFlow } = ???
  implicit val `case2`: JudgeFlow[???] { type Out = TextFlow } = ???
  implicit val `case3`: JudgeFlow[???] { type Out = RDDFlow } = ???
}
  
def judgeFlow[In](in: In)(implicit jf: JudgeFlow[In]): jf.Out = jf.judgeFlow(in)
```

But the trouble is that types are resolved at compile time. You seem to want to choose a case based on a value of string i.e. at runtime. So you can't return more specific types than just `Flow` at compile time.

[flatMap with Shapeless yield FlatMapper not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55708142/flatmap-with-shapeless-yield-flatmapper-not-found)

---

It's hard to guess your use case completely.

But using [Scala reflection](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/overview.html) you can try

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.reflect.runtime.currentMirror

def judgeFlow(path:String): Type = {
  Flow.getStoreType(path) match {
    case StoreType.tdw =>
      typeOf[DataFrameFlow]
    case StoreType.hdfs =>
      typeOf[TextFlow]
  }
}

def createFlow(typeInfo: Type): Flow = {
  val constructorSymbol = typeInfo.decl(termNames.CONSTRUCTOR).asMethod
  val classSymbol = typeInfo.typeSymbol.asClass
  val classMirror = currentMirror.reflectClass(classSymbol)
  val constructorMirror = classMirror.reflectConstructor(constructorSymbol)
  constructorMirror().asInstanceOf[Flow]
}
```

Comment: Hi Dmytro, I think your point is I can't do this in compile time, however, what if simply do this in runtime? I know there is some reflect strategy by which I can get declared constructor, however it does not totally solve my problem, because I still need something that can "operate" over types during runtime, for example, is type `A` derived from type/type parameter/trait `B`, or is `A` totally equal type `B`. I know there are something such as `typeOf`/`getClass`/`ClassTag` from with I can eventually get that, but I got really lost here and I wonder if there is somewhat a package or somethin

Comment: @calvin `ClassTag`/`TypeTag` are to persist compile-time information for runtime. *"however, what if simply do this in runtime?"* Ok, but you have to return some type at compile time. So `/*1*/` will be just `Flow` (not specific subtypes). Is it ok?

Comment: Yes, this function can return anything now, even strings like `com.xxx.xxx.DataFrameFlow`, and I can do instantiation with `java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor`, do invoking with some `java.lang.reflect.Method`, and doing type comparing with some other methods. However, these ways are confusing, and sometimes they need extra manipulating, such as handling companion objects, so I wonder if there are some easy/neat solutions here, maybe some functions like `<type_traits>` in C++?

Comment: @calvin I reread your question and maybe I misunderstood it firstly. You don't want `judgeFlow` to return instances of `Flow` with specific subtypes, you want it to return some type/class information about instances. You should add some examples of using `judgeFlow`, `createFlow` (as you imagine this). Inputs and desired outputs. Current behavior, what's wrong with it, and how you want to fix it. (Yes, type info can be strings or tags.)

Comment: @calvin I'm not so familiar with type traits in C++. Either you have enough information to do your manipulations at compile time and then you can do that with macros, Shapeless, compile-time reflection, implicits/typeclasses etc. Or you have necessary information only at runtime (this seems to be the case since you start from runtime string `path`, or is it a compile-time string literal?) and then you have to work with runtime reflection (Java reflection: `Class`, `Method` etc. or Scala reflection: `Symbol`, `Type`, `Mirror` etc.). If you want better answer...

Comment: @calvin ... you should provide more details in your question.

Comment: @calvin If you have issues with performing Scala tasks (*"handling companion objects"*) using Java reflection you can try Scala reflection (sometypes it's easier because it's Scala-specific, sometimes it's harder because it's more wordy).

Comment: @calvin I updated my answer with some Scala reflection code.