# How to refactor so I can return different types in my case statement and then execute the doobie queries

Tags: scala, types, scala-cats, doobie

Based on the match condition I will need to execute a different doobie query, and these queries may return different Right types in their Eithers.

The problem currently is that sometimes the Right of my either returns `SomeType1` and in another match branch in returns `SomeType2`.

Note: I actually don't care about the return type of this function, currently it is `List[User]` but I can make it `Unit` if it helps.

```
def blah(locationId: Int): ConnectionIO[Either[String, List[User]]] = 
(for {
    usersToUpdate <- EitherT.fromEither[ConnectionIO] (
       UserDao.getUsersByLocation(locationId) match {
           case Nil => 
        Left("...")
           case first :: _ => 
        SomeDao.blah2(..) // ConnectionIO[Either[String, SomeType1]]
           case ... => 
        SomeDao.blah(..) // ConnectionIO[Either[String, SomeType2]]

          }
       }
    )
   updatedUsers <- usersToUpdate.traverse { EitherT(_) }
} yield updatedUsers).value
```

Is it possible to get this to work or I have to figure out a different way to do this logic?

Comment: No matter how you refactor... you can not return different types from same method without using the umbrella common parent type.

Comment: The compiler must know what type to return from a method at compile time. So you can return different types from a method if you know **at compile time** which case you have (`Nil`, `first :: _` or `first :: second :: _`). This can be achieved with type classes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64002546 Otherwise you'll have to return some common type like `ConnectionIO[Either[String, SomeType1 | SomeType2]]` (Scala 3), `ConnectionIO[Either[String, Either[SomeType1, SomeType2]]]`, `ConnectionIO[Either[String, SomeParentType]]` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508077

Comment: Also `ConnectionIO[Either[String, _]]`