# Problem determining parameter type when calling a method

Tags: scala, generics

I'm sorry for the vague or possibly incorrect question, but I'm not even sure how to state my problem in one sentence.

I have 2 traits:

```
trait Property[T] {
  val name: String

  def conformsTo(rule: Rule[T]): Boolean
}
```

and

```
trait Rule[T] {
  def evaluate(valueToCheck: T): Boolean
}
```

I have a list of concrete classes implementing `Property` and a map of `Rule` implementations, where both parameterized types can either be a `Double` or a `String`.
When traversing this list, for each `Property` instance I pass in a concrete `Rule` implementation to the `conformsTo` method, the compiler however errors with a type mismatch.

So in a broader sense, what I'm trying to achieve is to have a list of attributes that can be evaluated based on a given set of rules of different types, without splitting these attributes into separate lists by type.

I tried tinkering with upper/lower bounds and implicit types but ended up with nothing.

The complete code:

```
trait Rule[T] {
  def evaluate(valueToCheck: T): Boolean
}

case class GreaterThan(value: Double) extends Rule[Double] {
  override def evaluate(valueToCheck: Double): Boolean = {
    valueToCheck > this.value
  }
}

case class LessThan(value: Double) extends Rule[Double] {
  override def evaluate(valueToCheck: Double): Boolean = {
    valueToCheck < this.value
  }
}

case class Is(value: String) extends Rule[String] {
  override def evaluate(valueToCheck: String): Boolean = {
    valueToCheck == this.value
  }
}

case class isNot(value: String) extends Rule[String] {
  override def evaluate(valueToCheck: String): Boolean = {
    valueToCheck != this.value
  }
}

trait Property[T] {
  val name: String

  def conformsTo(rule: Rule[T]): Boolean
}

case class DoubleProperty(name: String, value: Double) extends Property[Double] {
  override def conformsTo(rule: Rule[Double]): Boolean = rule.evaluate(value)
}

case class StringProperty(name: String, value: String) extends Property[String] {
  override def conformsTo(rule: Rule[String]): Boolean = rule.evaluate(value)
}

object Evaluator extends App {

  val ruleMap = Map(
    "name1" -> GreaterThan(123),
    "name1" -> LessThan(500),
    "name2" -> GreaterThan(1000),
    "name3" -> Is("something"))
  val numericProperty = DoubleProperty("name1", 600)
  val numericProperty2 = DoubleProperty("name2", 1000)
  val stringProperty = StringProperty("name3", "something")
  val stringProperty2 = StringProperty("name4", "something")

  val attributes = List(
    numericProperty,
    numericProperty2,
    stringProperty,
    stringProperty2)

  val nonConforming = attributes
    .filter(x => ruleMap.contains(x.name))
    .filter(x => !x.conformsTo(ruleMap(x.name))).toList

}
```

the error:

```
type mismatch;
 found   : Product with Rule[_ >: String with Double] with java.io.Serializable
 required: Rule[(some other)<root>._1]
Note: Any >: _1 (and Product with Rule[_ >: String with Double] with java.io.Serializable <: Rule[_ >: String with Double]), but trait Rule is invariant in type T.
You may wish to define T as -T instead. (SLS 4.5)
    .filter(x => !x.conformsTo(ruleMap(x.name))).toList
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, based on error message it can make sense to extend `Rule` from `Product with Serializable`

https://typelevel.org/blog/2018/05/09/product-with-serializable.html

Then error message changes to:

```
type mismatch;
 found   : App.Rule[_1(in value $anonfun)] where type _1(in value $anonfun) >: String with Double
 required: App.Rule[<root>._1]
```

Secondly, you can make `Rule` contravariant

```
trait Rule[-T] extends Product with Serializable {
  def evaluate(valueToCheck: T): Boolean
}
```

```
type mismatch;
 found   : App.Rule[String with Double]
 required: App.Rule[_1]
```

and `Property` covariant

```
trait Property[+T] {
  val name: String
  def conformsTo(rule: Rule[T]): Boolean
}
```

```
type mismatch;
 found   : App.Rule[String with Double]
 required: App.Rule[Any]
```

The thing is that this not gonna work with `List`. Elements of `attributes` have types `Property[Double]` and `Property[String]`. But when you add them to a list they lost their individual types and become just `Property[Any]` (`Property[Double | String]` if there were union types in Scala 2).

Similarly, values of `ruleMap` have types `Rule[Double]` and `Rule[String]`. But when you put them with some keys into a map they lost their individual types and become just `Rule[Double with String]` (or even `Rule[Nothing]`).

If you didn't modify variances of `Property` and `Rule` then the types would be `Property[_]` and `Rule[_]` (actually, `Property[_1]` and `Rule[_2]`) where type parameters don't correspond to each other.

But the signature of `conformsTo` says that `property.conformsTo(rule)` compiles only when arguments have types `Property[T]` and `Rule[T]` for the same `T`, which you can't guarantee.

You could try to use [`HList`](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#heterogenous-lists) instead of `List` and [`HMap`](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#heterogenous-maps) instead of `Map` in order to keep individual types of elements. But then in order to make `filter` work you should know whether `ruleMap.contains(x.name)` at compile time. So you would have to make keys have singleton types and trait `Property` to depend on this one more type parameter `trait Property[+T, S <: String with Singleton] { val name: S ...`

[Why Does This Type Constraint Fail for List[Seq[AnyVal or String]]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62365774/why-does-this-type-constraint-fail-for-listseqanyval-or-string/)

[Scala: verify class parameter is not instanceOf a trait at compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61177962/scala-verify-class-parameter-is-not-instanceof-a-trait-at-compile-time)

[How to make a typeclass works with an heterogenous List in scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64011072/how-to-make-a-typeclass-works-with-an-heterogenous-list-in-scala)

[Use the lowest subtype in a typeclass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61392874/use-the-lowest-subtype-in-a-typeclass)

[flatMap with Shapeless yield FlatMapper not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55708142/flatmap-with-shapeless-yield-flatmapper-not-found)

---

The easiest way to make your code compile is

```
val nonConforming = attributes
  .filter(x => ruleMap.contains(x.name))
  .filter{
    case x: Property[t] => !x.conformsTo(ruleMap(x.name).asInstanceOf[Rule[t]])
  }
```

Comment: I believe the simples solution would be to make a simple ADT for the possible types for attributes and rules.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez What if we do `filter{ case x: Property[t] => x.conformsTo(ruleMap(x.name).asInstanceOf[Rule[t]]) }`?

Comment: I really do not know too much about type patterns, I believe that works but in my mind it is unsafe.

Comment: Thank you for the answers.
@LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez - are you able to elaborate, you mean an algebraic data type?

Comment: @hdevone yeah something like `sealed trait ValidType` - `final case class DoubleType(d: Double) extends ValidType`, etc and then `trait Property[T <: ValidType] {` & `trait Rule[T <: ValidType] {` - That way in the filter you can match both the **property** and **rule** to determine they both have the same type, but it can be quite verbose.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Do you mean something like that https://scastie.scala-lang.org/iD7fNrGKTaebDGJCcUTX6Q ?

Comment: @DmytroMitin yeah, as I said, your alternative is probably safe and obviously shorter. But being honest I would do what you did in that Scastie since that way I am sure it is safe. Note that, such a decision is my personal one, mainly driven my ignorance and _(somewhat)_ fear to type checks; not saying OP should do that.

Comment: Thank you for all your answers. I guess I'll make do with the manual type check approach until union types come with scala 3 :).

Comment: @hdevone Union types can help with `Property[Any]` or `Property[ValidType]` -> `Property[Double | String]` but they can't help with ordinary list and map not preserving individual element types so that you have type mismatch `attributes: Seq[Property[Double | String]]` vs. `ruleMap: Map[String, Rule[Double with String]]`. Even with union types you have mismatch union type vs. intersection type.