# Split list of algebraic date type to lists of branches?

Tags: scala, shapeless, hlist

I'm pretty new to shapeless so the question might be easy.

Here is the ADT:

```
sealed trait Test

final case class A() extends Test
final case class B() extends Test
final case class C() extends Test
...
final case class Z() extends Test
```

Is it possible to write a function without ***extremely cumbersome*** pattern matching?

```
def split(lst: List[Test]): List[A] :: List[B] :: ... :: HNil = //
```

Comment: You could try `groupBy`, perhaps, especially if you have control over `Test`

Comment: @user The problem with `groupBy` is that it's not typesafe and would require some sort of casting for this particular case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At compile time all elements of `List` have the same static type `Test`, so there is no way to distinguish elements `A`, `B`, `C`... using compile-time technique only (Shapeless, type classes, implicits, macros, compile-time reflection). The elements are distinguishable at runtime only, so you have to use some runtime technique (pattern matching, casting, runtime reflection).

[Why Does This Type Constraint Fail for List[Seq[AnyVal or String]]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62365774/why-does-this-type-constraint-fail-for-listseqanyval-or-string/)

[Scala: verify class parameter is not instanceOf a trait at compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61177962/scala-verify-class-parameter-is-not-instanceof-a-trait-at-compile-time)

[flatMap with Shapeless yield FlatMapper not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55708142/flatmap-with-shapeless-yield-flatmapper-not-found)

Try `split` into a Map using runtime reflection

```
def split(lst: List[Test]): Map[String, List[Test]]  =
  lst.groupBy(_.getClass.getSimpleName)

split(List(C(), B(), A(), C(), B(), A()))
// HashMap(A -> List(A(), A()), B -> List(B(), B()), C -> List(C(), C()))
```

or `split` into a `HList` using Shapeless + runtime reflection

```
import shapeless.labelled.{FieldType, field}
import shapeless.{::, Coproduct, HList, HNil, LabelledGeneric, Poly1, Typeable, Witness}
import shapeless.ops.coproduct.ToHList
import shapeless.ops.hlist.Mapper
import shapeless.ops.record.Values
import shapeless.record._
import scala.annotation.implicitNotFound
    
object listPoly extends Poly1 {
  implicit def cse[K <: Symbol, V]: Case.Aux[FieldType[K, V], FieldType[K, List[V]]] = null
}

// modified shapeless.ops.maps.FromMap
@implicitNotFound("Implicit not found: FromMapWithDefault[${R}]. Maps can only be converted to appropriate Record types.")
trait FromMapWithDefault[R <: HList] extends Serializable {
  // if no value by this key use default, if can't cast return None
  def apply[K, V](m: Map[K, V], default: V): Option[R]
}
object FromMapWithDefault {
  implicit def hnilFromMap[T]: FromMapWithDefault[HNil] =
    new FromMapWithDefault[HNil] {
      def apply[K, V](m: Map[K, V], default: V): Option[HNil] = Some(HNil)
    }


  implicit def hlistFromMap[K0, V0, T <: HList]
  (implicit wk: Witness.Aux[K0], tv: Typeable[V0], fmt: FromMapWithDefault[T]): FromMapWithDefault[FieldType[K0, V0] :: T] =
    new FromMapWithDefault[FieldType[K0, V0] :: T] {
      def apply[K, V](m: Map[K, V], default: V): Option[FieldType[K0, V0] :: T] = {
        val value = m.getOrElse(wk.value.asInstanceOf[K], default)
        for {
          typed <- tv.cast(value)
          rest <- fmt(m, default)
        } yield field[K0](typed) :: rest
      }
    }
}

def split[T, C <: Coproduct, L <: HList, L1 <: HList](lst: List[T])(
  implicit
  labelledGeneric: LabelledGeneric.Aux[T, C],
  toHList: ToHList.Aux[C, L],
  mapper: Mapper.Aux[listPoly.type, L, L1],
  fromMapWithDefault: FromMapWithDefault[L1],
  values: Values[L1]
): values.Out = {
  val groupped = lst.groupBy(_.getClass.getSimpleName).map { case (k, v) => Symbol(k) -> v }
  fromMapWithDefault(groupped, Nil).get.values
}
```

Testing:

```
sealed trait Test
final case class A() extends Test
final case class B() extends Test
final case class C() extends Test
final case class Z() extends Test

val res = split(List[Test](C(), B(), A(), C(), B(), A())) 
// List(A(), A()) :: List(B(), B()) :: List(C(), C()) :: List() :: HNil
res: List[A] :: List[B] :: List[C] :: List[Z] :: HNil
```

[Scala 3 collection partitioning with subtypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69483366/scala-3-collection-partitioning-with-subtypes) (Scala 2/3)

Comment: Would it be possible to use macros to generate code that uses `asInstanceOf` and does the cumbersome pattern matching the OP mentioned?

Comment: @user I guess so. For example I used Shapeless + runtime reflection.

Comment: @user Hiding pattern matching is easy. Runtime reflection (`.getClass.getSimpleName`) is enough, we don't need macros. Most of work is with transforming the result into an HList as OP wanted.